# Trying to find the index of a word within a line (measured as number of words)

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I have the following code, which checks a line. Counts some words and tallies the frequency each word occurs. Basically, I'd like to add in a counter so that for each word (gotten by getNextWord), it will record the number of that word as wordCount in the struct word_t (eg. if the line is "all, cats! swim very far", I need it to record 0 for all, 1 for cats, 2 for swim, etc)This is the function I'm working on:

```
void
func4(line_t * linePtr, int argnum, char * argval[]) {

    int getfrequency(line_t* linePtr, char* checkword);
    word_t word;
    int Size;
    int i;
    int k=0;
    int wordfound[MAX_QUERYLENGTH]; /* 1 if query term matches word in line */
    for(i = 1; i < argnum; i++,k++) {
        int freq = 0;
        int offsetval = 0;
        int* offset = &offsetval;
        wordfound[i] = 0; 


        if (wordfound[i] == 1) {
            freq = getfrequency(linePtr, argval[i]);            
            /* this is where I require access to the index */
        }
    }                   
}
```

My struct is defined here. Just note that stopIndex and startIndex are measured in characters. The index I'm looking for, measured in words, will be called wordCount (listed below).

```
typedef struct word_t {
  int startIndex;
  int stopIndex;
  int wordCount;
  int frequency;
  char buf[MAX_LINELEN];
  int wordSz; /* szie of word*/
} word_t;
```

Just for reference I'll put function call here too:
    while (-1 != (line.lineLength = getline((char**) &line.buf, &maxSz, stdin))) {
        /* more code in here! */
        stage4(&line,argc,argv,&word);
    }

I have tried adding word.wordCount++ after the call to getNextWord, but this did not work (even after initialising to 0 in the while loop where the function call is). I have also been trying to use wordPtr->wordCount, but am not getting what I want.

Thank you.

Further clarification:
I am taking command line arguments where argv is argval. These make up query terms. I then search a text (stdin) for the query terms line by line. The frequency is the frequency that a word that matches a query term shows up in 1 line of the text (eg. if query terms are "cat hat mat" and the first line of stdin is "cat cat cat sat that", then the frequency of cat would be 3).

What I need is to take each line of stdin and record the word number (wordCount) for each word that matches a query term (match is determined using strncasecmp). That is, if query is "cat hat mat" and the first line of stdin is "cat cat cat sat mat", I need to record that the first cat is at wordCount = 0, the second cat is at wordCount = 1, the 3rd cat is at wordCount = 2 and mat is at wordCount = 4. I just need a way of storing each of these wordCounts in my struct, for later access.

Comment: Your program and problem description are somewhat confusing. You read lines from `stdin`, but also look at the arguments. Do you need the word frequencies just for the words that are passed as arguments? You might want to clarify how your program works with example call, line input and expected output. It would also help to get the definitions of the various types you have defined.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback! I'll edit post and will comment with what's going on.

Comment: As for the index: I think you could just keep a position count in the loop where you call `getNextWord` and re-define the meaning of `wordfound`: Make it -1 if the word wasn't found and the index if it was found.

Comment: A stylistic side note: Please don't declare external functions inside the functions where they are used. It is allowed in C, but it makes the code hard to read. Put them at the top of your source code (or, better yet, inside a header) to separate implementation and interface cleanly.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for the help with style. I'll be sure to clean it up once I'm finished (just to avoid confusing myself now) and will keep that in mind for next time. I've also edited to add clarification to my question. How would changing wordfound (so that it's -1 if word not found) impact this, sorry? I did have word.wordCount++ just under my call to getNextWord, but it wasn't working (it's returning an address rather than the count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this a bit differently. You can get the frequency and the first occurrence of a word in a single loop. I'd also swap the inner and outer loops, so you don't have to tokenise the loop all over again.

Keep track of the word index with a counter for each word. Similarly keep an array of frequencies.

```
void stage4(line_t * linePtr, int argnum, char * argval[])
{
    word_t word;
    int wordindex[MAX_QUERYLENGTH];    /* First index in this line or -1 if none */
    int freq[MAX_QUERYLENGTH];         /* Frequency in this line */
    int count = 0;                     /* Word counter */

    int offsetval = 0;
    int* offset = &offsetval;
    int i;    

    /* Initialise */
    for(i = 1; i < argnum; i++) {
        wordindex[i] = -1;
        freq[i] = 0;
    }

    word = getNextWord(linePtr->buf, linePtr->lineLength, offset, &word);

    while (0 != word.stopIndex) {           
        for(i = 1; i < argnum; i++,k++) {
            if (0 == strcasecmp(argval[i], word.buf)) {
                /* Found a word, update frequency and pos */
                if (freq[i] == 0) wordindex[i] = count;
                freq[i]++;

                /* Assuming argval is unique, there are no further hits */
                break;
            }
        }                   

        /* Update word count and read next word */
        count++;
        word = getNextWord(linePtr->buf, linePtr->lineLength, offset, &word);
    }    

    /* Print frequencies */    
    for(i = 1; i < argnum; i++) {
        if (wordindex[i] >= 0) printf("%s: %d\n", argval[i], freq[i]);
    }   
}
```

This code isn't tested, because I haven't got access to your (rather complicated) reading functions. It also doesn't solve how to store the local frequencies and positions for further use. But it should give you a general ide how to go about this problem.

(The -1 for the word index is redundant here, because the absence of a word is already represented by a zero frequency, but it could be used if frequency was an accumulated value over all lines.)

Comment: I do apologise. The whole thing is very complicated at the moment. I really appreciate your help, thank you. The whole thing works, except the index is always 0 (which I admit, is almost definitely due to my complicated function and the fact that you can't access it). I'm still not 100% that I understand how to count the index myself either sorry

Comment: Okay, I had forgotten to update `count`, sorry for that. I'll edit the post.